# angularJS window.open(Url) leave the window open if document is already opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am opening a Word document in my angularJS with window.open(docUrl). Could please anyone tell me why the new tab remain open if the document is already opened and active?
While on closing and re-opening the document behave normally where a new tab open with prompt of open, save and save as options and as soon as document is opened or saved, the new tab automatically close but it is not the case when document is already active. Is there any way of closing the tab?

Comment: it might just be me, but could you make this clearer? Specify how it behaves right now, and how you want it to behave.

Comment: at first, document open up fine and new tab automatically get closed as soon as document is opened. Now, if i leave this specific document opened and click on button to reopen it, the new tab will open with the prompts of open, save and save as and when i click on any of the button, the new tab remains open. remember the previously opened document hasn't been closed. Now my question, is there a way to close this newly opened tab which is not closing by itself if previously opened document is not closed.

Comment: Is it possible to explain with some code, a plunker or fiddle might help?

Comment: I have replaced window.open(Url) with window.location.assign(Url) to avoid new tab. It is the IE which behaving badly while Chrome, Safari and Firefox are working fine. Now, IE is just don't do anything if document is already open. It just highlight the document in the window which I am happy with.